# If I glue $\Sigma_{n-1}^1$ and $\Sigma_{1}^1$ do I get $\Sigma_{n}$ or $\Sigma_{n}^1$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, surfaces

This is possibly a very stupid question to ask but I will ask this anyway. If I glue $\Sigma_{n-1}^1$ and $\Sigma_{1}^1$ do I get $\Sigma_{n}$ or $\Sigma_{n}^1$. In other words, if a punctured $n-1$ torus glued with a punctured torus, will I get a n-torus or a-n torus with a boundary. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Could you please respond to my comment about notation on your previous question?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese From lecture notes and I have seen it on stachexchange as well. Is it not a standard notation?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Could you link to somewhere that uses this notation? In your last question, your language suggested the superscript referred to the number of boundary components, but now your language seems to suggest that it refers to the number of punctures - these are two different things.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese the superscript is for the boundary components

Comment: Then you shouldn't say punctures as this is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been established, $\Sigma_{n-1}^1$ is a genus $n - 1$ surface with one boundary component, not one puncture (it's not clear what it would mean to glue punctured surfaces).

Given two surfaces $\Sigma_g^1$ and $\Sigma_h^1$, we can form a new surface by identifying the boundary of $\Sigma_g^1$ with $\Sigma_h^1$. The resulting surface has no boundary components, and it is not hard to see that the genus is the sum of the initial genera, so the new surface is $\Sigma_{g+h}$. In fact, this procedure is nothing but the connected sum of $\Sigma_g$ and $\Sigma_h$. In particular, $\Sigma_{n-1}^1$ glued to $\Sigma_1^1$ gives $\Sigma_n$.

For $n = 3$, this construction can be seen below (image modified from the one found [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Connected_sum.png))

$\hspace{35mm}$[image]